# 'Follow' or 'Subscribe' method

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I want to know how Follow system in Twitter or Subscribe in Youtube method in PHP and MySQL. How it is work in the database?

Do I have to create "subscribes" table which contain information for a user that following a content/other user's publication.

E.g If someone follow/sub someone, my app create a new row in the table example user:userA action:follow who:userB

So if userA open userB's content, I have to search this table if userA already follow userB or not? Or there are easier method?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no magic about it, if you want to track something, you have to have a table/field somewhere for it, and you have to read it when you need it.  You seem to be on the right track, why not give a try and let us know how it goes :-)

Answer (score 1):

For an easy subscription System:

**table_user**

- id
- name

**table_subscriber**

- id_user_subscriber    -> points to table_user -> id
- id_user_provider     -> points to table_user -> id

if you want to keep track if the subscriber has seen the new post alredy, you have to create another table:

**table_post**

- id
- name

**table_subscriber_post**

- id_user_subscriber   -> points to table_user -> id
- id_post             -> points to table_post -> id

If the user has seen the post, create an entry in the table above